# How to fetch a string resource in a class library

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm working on a class library which contains several .resw resource files and pages. The question is, how to fetch the string and use it for UI component properties.

Better to show the case in another way. First, please refer to to image for the solution structure:

[image]

From the picture, "MobileReplicaBase" is a class library. Please not the two selected file. In "UIresources.resw", I defined a string resource:

[image]

And trying to use it in a button control in EdicolaPage:

```
<Button x:Name="mOpenBtn" Grid.Row="4" x:Uid="OpenBtn" Visibility="{x:Bind Path=type, Converter={StaticResource typeStringToVisibilityConverterForOpenButton}}" Tag="{x:Bind Path=productCode}" Click="mOpenBtn_Click"/>
```

But this won't work, the Content property for the button is only an empty string. What I can guess is that, the application is trying to load the "OpenBtn" resource from resource map in project "MobileReplica", which is currently the start up project in the solution.

Note: the button may be in a datatemplate in a GridView, so fetch the resource in C# code may not be a good idea.

Comment: The question is clear, but I don't see any attempt at your issue. Can you please update your post to include code you've tried, what isn't working so we can better assist you.

Comment: Did you try this? `var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("YourLibrary/Resources"); var resource = resourceLoader.GetString("resourceName");` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest

Comment: @mm8 I know that works in C# code. But sorry, as I said, the button is actually a part of a datatemplate which is used for a GridView. So it's really not a good idea to implement it in C# code, better in the xaml file. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex.Y: How about using the [x:Uid directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-uid-directive) then? Did you try it?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, that is what exactly I'm trying. But does not work.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I just updated the post for some more detail. But the images are missing, seems due to some server issues. Hope the description and xaml code can help you a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Use following code to access resource in a class lib:

```
<Button x:Uid="/{library_name}/{resource_file_name}/{resource_name}"/>
```

In my case, I should use:

```
<Button x:Uid="/MobileReplicaBase/UIresources/OpenBtn">
```

To access to the resource.